# How to set array of colors to the border

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here i am trying to set the multiple colors to the user profile icon border.

```
                CAGradientLayer *layer2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
                NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                                   (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                                   nil];
```

Below line is giving me error i want set it's border color by adding color from the array but it is giving me error.How can i pass array of colors to setBorderColor: method.

```
                [layer2 setBorderColor:colors];

                //below code is working fine
                [layer2 setFrame:cell.userIcon.layer.frame];
                [cell.userIcon.layer insertSublayer:layer2 atIndex:0];
                cell.userIcon.clipsToBounds = YES; // Important!
```

Comment: Check out some other question that already solved this like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193993/how-to-make-a-gradient-border-of-uiview) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528782/how-to-make-calayer-border-with-gradient-or-multiple-colors)

Comment: i have already checked them and there is no passing of array in that only a single color  @Tj3n

Comment: And? Did you follow the answer in there?

Comment: yes they are passing a single color to the setBorderColor: method not an array @Tj3n

Comment: What makes you think you can pass an array of colors to a property that wants a single color? There's no way to achieve what you're trying without using another method.

Comment: so can you suggest me anything which will help me to achieve waht i want to @Cyrille

Comment: @Tj3n already suggested links for you in his first comment.

Comment: but those links are no longer useful to me as they pass a single color to the method i want other method or any other solution to my problem .@Cyrille

Comment: It's not single color, its gradient, you can pass just any color you want in there

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the `colors` and `borderColor` property. `colors` property can be set for the whole layer with multiple colors, however, `borderColor` does not accept an array of `CGColor`.

Here is a screenshot from the API documentation:

[image]

So, `setBorderColor` only accepts `CGColor`, but you are assigning an `NSArray` instead. `borderColor` property can **ONLY** be set by a single `CGColor`.

However, if you would like to add a single `CGColor` to the border color from an array, you could do the following. Just store `UIColor` in the array.

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIColor whiteColor],
                   [UIColor redColor],
                   nil];
```

And when you are trying to set to a layer, do the following:

```
[layer2 setBorderColor:((UIColor*)colors.firstObject).CGColor];
```

You can replace `colors.firstObject` to the `colors[0]` or `colors[1]`, depending on which color you need.

Comment: i want both the colors in the same border thats why i am using gradient, i am not going to use one by one from array i want both of them at a time.

Comment: thanks for the help but i want two colors in border at the same time.